# Cannot move files to a mounted gscfuse storage bucket (gcloud)

Tags: gcloud, gcsfuse

I'm having a problem almost exactly like this guy

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/issues/288

except that when they solved the problem they did not give enough details as to its solution.  I have a mounted storage bucket on a gcloud VM instance but I cannot write a file to the storage bucket.  It seems that my problem is that I have not given Google my authentication credentials.  I tried moving the credentials I used on my Mac over to the Linux computer but that so far has had no affect.  Here is the exact syntax:

```
str1 = "/home/kylefoley/byu_corpus_small/codes/My_Project_999.json"
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = str1
key = "9999"
```

I have successfully mounted the storage bucket with gcsfuse and can read files from it but when I try to write files to it I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build_index.py", line 638, in <module>
    determine_fork()
  File "build_index.py", line 635, in determine_fork
    main_fork(make_changes, len(rem_files), **kwargs)
  File "build_index.py", line 590, in main_fork
    save_iweb_pickle(dct, 'done_forks')
  File "/home/kylefoley/byu_corpus_small/code/byu_globals.py", line 27, in save_iweb_pickle
    pi.save_pickle(obj, name, 1)
  File "/home/kylefoley/byu_corpus_small/code/pickling.py", line 55, in save_pickle
    temp = open(name, "wb")
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error: '/mnt/disks/temp_dir/fix_mistakes/done_forks.pkl'
```

The aforementioned author solved the problem with

> My apologies. You're right. I misunderstood how authentication was working. Once I used gcloud auth login everything worked as expected.

But I can't figure out what he means by that. I would think it would have something to do with this module:

```
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
```

But I cannot figure out what to do with that module.  By the way my mountpoint is:

```
/mnt/disks/temp_dir/
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem in the following way: I had to go to Cloud API Access Scopes and verify under the VM configuration that it has read write or full access for storage. This involved pressing edit on the gcloud console which lists my instances.  At the bottom of the page, there was the limitation for storage which I changed to 'full'.  That did it.